# Eigen how to redistribute matrix values between zero and one

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

I have an Eigen matrix which is made of 3d vector coords, like this:

```
 Eigen::MatrixXd V(m,n);

 V <<
 0.07790318440941 ,  2.93084729477845 ,0
 4.39385211199504 , -6.85288411884976 ,0
 4.79942053354374 , -6.21531436940366 ,0
 4.66539716949595 , -5.80851415050593 ,0
 4.05673773136193 , -5.07476450520047 ,0
 3.86587436704604 , -5.95679712917311 ,0
 3.08037179920737 , -5.63304123859979 ,0
 3.63881426545377 , -6.81338736661468 ,0
 2.78034109511472 , -5.31824526094401 ,0
 2.49863667468366 , -4.42841643782729 ,0
 2.17676933907024 , -4.07462683865738 ,0
 1.83413618944877 , -3.26212572878334 ,0
 1.07129357571697 , -2.18125695931175 ,0
 0.87907607105418 , -1.47159374716746 ,0
 0.08567653234750 , -1.08987456825602 ,0
 1.05117121796426 , -0.398720814302181,0
 1.66426149221552 , -1.75532754482808 ,0
 2.41664333430651 , -2.85689387781641 ,0
 2.98468613101269 , -3.5024571681322  ,0
 3.25323005684431 , -3.9571858297574  ,0
 3.83255698099666 , -4.64451314176494 ,0
 3.1964644093435  , -4.78861644450358 ,0
 2.4829670255391  , -3.63635780062414 ,0
 1.70284397625327 , -2.49963796336543 ,0
```

(here the 3rd coord is missing)
I want them to span values between 0 and 1 only, where 0 is min,  and 1 max. In short, scale them. How can I do in Eigen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you plan on apply your own normalization scheme based on the values of your *dynamically sized* matrix at a given time, you might want to consider using a fixed-sized `const` matrix instead, otherwise you would be scaling your matrix entries differently depending on how the dynamic entries of the matrix looks at a given time. Alternatively, apply your normalization based on what you consider the static min/max value of a given coordinate.

Anyway, *if* you want to go ahead with this with your current matrix, have a look at the [`minCoeff()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#aaeb695853e9a28ba1dd54861d0cd9d8f) and [`maxCoeff()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#a6f3710cb36d81cd490b3a2ff3556471b) functions.

Compute `min` and `max` (over all matrix entries), subtract `min` from all matrix entries (*shift*), and thereafter divide all matrix entries by `max - min` (scale). The shift and scale linear operations will result in a matrix where the minimum entry is valued `0` and the maximum is valued `1`, and where all remaining values are linearly scaled accordingly, residing in `[0, 1]`.

Comment: A complete solution is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56116182/eigen-equivalent-of-matlab-rescale-command?noredirect=1#comment98866164_56116182